# why is my js script not displaying timer result?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a countdown timer hours minutes and second but the script I'm running doesn't display the results I wrote in the js script, can anyone correct my code so that the timer can work?
[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXnv6.jpg)

```js
let countdown = new date().getHours()
let $hours = document.getElementById('hours');
let $minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
let $second = document.getElementById('second');

setInterval(function() {
  var now = new hours();
  var timeleft = (countdown - now) / 1000;
  updateclock(timeleft);
}, 1000);

function updateclock(removebgtime) {
  let hours = Math.floor((remainingtime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  let minutes = Math.floor((remainingtime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))
  let second = Math.floor((remainingtime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  $hours.innerHTML = Number(hours);
  $minutes.innerHTML = Number(minutes);
  $second.innerHTML = Number(second);
}

function Number(Number) {
  return Number < 10 ? "0" + Number : Number;
}
```

Comment: `new hours();` is not a function

Comment: Also `new date()` needs to be `new Date()`, and `gethours()` should be `getHours()` - remember that JS is case-sensitive

Comment: On the other hand, `Number` _is_ a function, and should not be redefined.

Comment: I've changed it before but still not solved

Comment: If you have changed it before, why post the old code? Make sure your code is a [example], i.e. that it accurately represents your problem. It doesn't help a doctor to fix your broken arm if you give them X-rays from the _previous_ time your arm broke. Also, please pay attention to errors; if you ran your code, your console should be telling you `Hours` is not a function.

Comment: Your snippet says `Uncaught ReferenceError: date is not defined`. But `Date` is. To reiterate: remember that JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: sorry I've edited again, but the problem instead moved to the ,var now = new hours() ;

Comment: the code says that Uncaught referenceerror:hours is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues that I found in code.

- Your `countdown` variable must be defined as `let countdown = new Date().getHours()`. There is a syntax error there.
- Inside your `setInterval` function your `now` variable, if it is planning to get the current hour time it should be defined as `var now = new Date().getHours();`
- Also you have to redefine the `Number` function because `Number` is a datatype in javascript

Pseudo Code.

```
let countdown = new Date().getHours()
let $hours = document.getElementById('hours');
let $minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
let $second = document.getElementById('second');

setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getHours();
  var timeleft = (countdown - now) / 1000;
  updateclock(timeleft);
}, 1000);

function updateclock(remainingtime) {
  let hours = Math.floor((remainingtime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  let minutes = Math.floor((remainingtime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))
  let second = Math.floor((remainingtime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  $hours.innerHTML = parseToNumber(hours);
  $minutes.innerHTML = parseToNumber(minutes);
  $second.innerHTML = parseToNumber(second);
}

function parseToNumber(num) {
  return num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
}
```

Comment: I think you have to make a little fix of `updateclock` function. Parameter of the function has `removebgtime` name although further we can find it's usage under different name `remainingtime`.

Comment: @Jaood_xD Copy that

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment atm cause I need a bit more reputation. But why is this in your snippet

```
var now = new hours();
```

And why is this in your picture:

```
var now = new Hours();
```